# Create a pandas dataframe from a qrc resource file

Tags: python, pandas, pyside, qresource

I would like to save a CSV file into a qrc file and than read it putting its contents in a pandas dataframe, but I have some problems.

I created a qrc file called `res.qrc`:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
  <qresource>
    <file>dataset.csv</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I compiled it obtaining the `res_rc.py` file.

To read it I created a python script called `resource.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
import res_rc
from PySide.QtCore import *

file = QFile(":/dataset.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(file.fileName())
print(df)
```

But I obtain the error: `IOError: File :/dataset.csv does not exist`

All the files (`resource.py`, `res.qrs`, `res_rc.py`, `dataset.csv`) are in the same folder.

If I do `res_rc.qt_resource_data` I can see the contents.

How can I create the pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `qresource` is a virtual path that only Qt knows how to obtain it and can change internally without warnings, in these cases what must be done is to read all the data and convert it into a stream with `io.BytesIO`

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from PySide import QtCore
import res_rc


file = QtCore.QFile(":/dataset.csv")
if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    f = io.BytesIO(file.readAll().data())
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print(df)
```

Comment: thanks that solves my problem! Sorry I didn't really understand why we have to pass by BytesIO, could you please explain it?